# Java Base64 encode gives different results than C base64 encode

Tags: java, c, base64

I try to encode this byte array:

```
[237, 217, 204, 218, 109, 227, 157, 145, 35, 152, 85, 142, 182, 180, 120, 8]
```

Using Java library `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64` and `org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64.encode` this is the results:

```
[55, 100, 110, 77, 50, 109, 51, 106, 110, 90, 69, 106, 109, 70, 87, 79, 116, 114, 82, 52, 67, 65, 61, 61]
```

(note the double '=' padding character at the end)

Using `base64.c Copyright (c) 1995-2001 Kungliga Tekniska Högskolan (Royal Institute of Technology, Stockholm, Sweden)` this is the output:

```
[55, 100, 110, 77, 50, 109, 51, 106, 110, 90, 69, 106, 109, 70, 87, 79, 116, 114, 82, 52, 67, 66, 72, 114]
```

Can anyone explain why? How can I make the Java/C library works the same way?

Comment: I would read the base64 as text, as this is the point of using it ;)  It appears you are getting different padding at the end.  Do you know this is a problem. Base64 is not a well defined specifications.

Comment: Note: the C code is 13 years old, perhaps there is a newer version.

Answer (score 1):

Every Base64 ASCII character holds 6 bits information (2<sup>6</sup> = 64), so 4 Base64 characters hold 3 bytes information. You have 16 bytes, so one byte remains at the end, needing 2 Base64 characters, and to make the group up to 4 chars, two padding `=`s are added.

Mind: with JavaSE 8 came a class [Base64](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) to replace several older class around.

Base64 has several fields of application, with various little changes: padding can be left out, line breaks added to limit line length, and so on. Java 8's Base64 even has an option for a non-compatible URL and file name safeversion, where `+` and `/` are replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Base64 works on blocks of 3 bytes, and the `=` padding is there to bring the output size up to a multiple of 3.  This padding is optional, and if is not there then you can simply add it manually by checking the array length before trying to decode using the Java code.